# Need help with ntlm auth in Squid 2.7 and Active Directory group permission

Tags: debian, proxy, squid

I'm having problems with squid and NTLM auth, I already have ntlm auth (http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Ntlm) working so only logged users to the AD can navigate through the proxy.

Now I need to set an **ACL** with **dstdomains** so I can set a diferent set of websites on each group of the Active Directory, I already try the guide [ntlm with groups](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/NtlmWithGroups) but can't get that to work.

Anyone who has a similar scenario that can give some advice?

Btw, I'm using Squid 2.7 on a Debian Lenny server.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the last time I implemented something like this I used IP subnets instead of AD groups using [squidguard](http://www.squidguard.co.uk). I believe groups shouldn't be a problem but would be easier if you could post your squid.conf and an example of the group names and any error messages you're seeing?

Comment: I quit this idea a couple of months ago and I did exactly what you suggest, a pfsense with squid/squidguard and vlans/subnets with different permissions . Thanks!